# Loading indicator in redux and react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using redux in my react app. When page loads , I am fetching a set of data over api in useEffect. My redux store has a loading reducer , which when an action is fired ,will be set to true.

The problem i am experiencing is there is a  the page loads with no data first and then it shows loading indicator next .

I want to show loading indicator from page loading . I understand why it is happening, but couldn't get proper way to solve this.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue but I have a way to solve for every time when the page is loaded/re-loaded the loader should be by-default set to visible and when the data is fetched we can just set it hidden